# Why is $\int_0^{x}\eta \cdot g(\eta) d \eta > 0 \;\;\forall \;\;x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ assuming that $ g(x) > 0$ for all x?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-system

$g(x_1)$ is a nonlinear function with $ g(x_1) > 0 \;\;\forall \;\;x_1\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ and $ g(x_1 = 0) = 0 $.

I have read in "The Variable Gradient Method of Generating Liapunov Functions with Application to Automatic Control Systems by John E. Gibson" that

$\int_0^{x_1}\eta \cdot g(\eta) d \eta > 0 \;\;\forall \;\;x_1\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $

but I don't really understand why.

The argumentation in the book was:

"... Since the
nonlinearity was specified as $y = x\cdot g(x)$, $g(x)$ is always
positive if the nonlinearity lies in the first and third
quadrant, and, under these conditions, the integral involving $g(x_1)$ is always positive ..."

In my case the nonlinearity lies in the first and secound quadrant, but I just can't understand why hence the integral $\int_0^{x_1}\eta \cdot g(\eta) d \eta$ is always positive.

Any tip or answer is helpful, I am trying to understand why it is the case.

Comment: If $x>0$, $\eta g(\eta)>0$ for all $\eta\in(0,x)$. So the integral is positive. What about if $x<0$?

Comment: It is a well known result in integration that of $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in X$, then $\int_X f\,d\mu>0$ (Here $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a measure space) In your case, you $X=(0,\infty)$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. The idea behind this is to see that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu(f>\frac1n)\leq n\int_X f\,d\mu$. So, if $\int_Xf=0$, then $\mu(f>\frac1n)=0$ for all $n$ and so, $\mu(f>0)=\mu(\bigcup_n\{f>\tfrac1n\})\leq\sum_n\mu(f>\frac1n)=0$.

Comment: When $x<0$, then you your integral becomes $-\int^0_x \eta\,g(\eta)\,d\eta$, which is strictly positive for the same reason as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. I can't believe that I didn't understand it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

A simple derivation is the following:

Make the change of variable $\eta=\theta x$ in the integral. Then the integral can be written as
$$\int_0^x{\eta g(\eta)d\eta}=x^2\int_0^1\theta g(\theta x)d\theta>0 \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}
$$
since $\int_0^1\theta g(\theta x)d\theta>0 $ due to $\theta g(\theta x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$  and $\theta\in(0,1]$.